# WebJob only has access to 2 GiB of memory when App Service Plan has 7 GiB

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have an Azure App Service Plan as the following, which is supposed to have 7 GB of memory.

```
P2V2
420 total ACU
7 GB memory
Dv2-Series compute equivalent
83.22 USD/Month (Estimated)
```

I am using this to host a single App that with a single Continuous WebJob. Sure there is the website for the App itself but I do not use it at all.

Also there is only 1 instance of the App in my Service Plan so it isn't due to multiple instances sharing the total available 7 GiB memory.

The Service Plan has 2 deployment slots, 1 for Production and 1 for Staging. Both Apps (In Production and Staging) are turned off because WebJob can keep running while the App itself is off.

Here is what I see that is puzzling. From the App Service Plan overview page it says I am using around 45% of the total memory available.
[image]

But I ran into OutOfMemoryException sometimes so I started checking to see how much memory my WebJob is actually using.

It turns out that it is using 1.6 GiB out of 2 GiB available physical memory, not the 7 GiB that I was expecting.

The way I am getting the current memory is via the following code

```
var currentMemory = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
var totalMemory = GC.GetGCMemoryInfo().TotalAvailableMemoryBytes;
```

According to documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gcmemoryinfo.totalavailablememorybytes?view=net-6.0#System_GCMemoryInfo_TotalAvailableMemoryBytes

> This property value will be the value of the COMPlus_GCHeapHardLimit environment variable, or the Server.GC.HeapHardLimit value in runtimeconfig.json, if either is set.
>
> If the program is run in a container, this value is an implementation-defined fraction of the container's size.
>
> Otherwise, the value of the property is the physical memory on the machine that was available for the garbage collector to use when the last garbage collection occurred.

Since I do not have environment variable, runtimeconfig.json set and it is not a container, I think `GC.GetGCMemoryInfo().TotalAvailableMemoryBytes` is correctly returning total physical memory available to my WebJob on the VM, which is 2 GiB.

I also found this article thanks to Vova's comment below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-availability-performance-application-issues#i-see-the-message--worker-process-requested-recycle-due-to--percent-memory--limit---how-do-i-address-this-issue-

It does make sense; at the same time, it seems to me the article is specific to the App Service itself. WebJob runs as a separate process from the web site. Though the symptom is the same. It seems my WebJob is JIT to 32bit rather than 64bit.

My WebJob build configuration

```
.NET 6 Console Application
Platform: Any CPU
```

Regardless, my App Service Configuration is set to x64 as shown below.
[image]

I'm trying to understand what I am doing wrong because I assume Azure is doing the right thing here.

I am using Azure App Service to run a WebJob so my goal is to maximize memory available to the WebJob with the smallest/cheapest SKU available.

Comment: Did you build x86 or x64?

Comment: Build platform target is Any CPU. App Service configuration setting for Platform type is x64

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the problem with this is in how I run my WebJob via the `run.cmd` startup script that I create in my ADO pipeline.

`dotnet MyWebJob.dll` results in `GC.GetGCMemoryInfo().TotalAvailableMemoryBytes` return 2 GiB as total available memory for my WeJob while my WebJob itself `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64` consumes only 1.5 GiB of memory.

Since my ADO pipeline also produces an executable specific for the platform, Windows, I also have an EXE that I could run. Start my WebJob by invoking the EXE `MyWebJob.exe` results in `GC.GetGCMemoryInfo().TotalAvailableMemoryBytes` return 5.5 GiB as total available memory for my WeJob while my WebJob itself `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64` bloats to 3.5 GiB of memory.

The reason for these 2 different behaviors is that the `Path` environment variable contains both dotnet SDK x86 and x64, with dotnet x86 comes before dotnet x64 in the value. As a result, when I do `dotnet MyWebJob.dll`, the system is using the x86 dotnet runtime, as evident in the debug console.

```
C:\home>dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.100
 Commit:    9e8b04bbff

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x86
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.0
  Commit:  4822e3c3aa
```

I modified my ADO task that is responsible of generating the startup script for my WebJob to explicitly use the x64 version of dotnet. `[01/07/2022 00:21:06 > 52cb62: INFO] C:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\MyWebJob\n04q3opt.krt>"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" MyWebJob.dll`  and this fixed the issue.

The result is the same as running the EXE directly without using `dotnet` as I showed above.

Comment: A webjob is started by Kudu by running D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\triggered\WEBJOBNAME\run.cmd
which typically contains
dotnet WEBJOBNAME.dll %*
However, Kudu's environment (Path variable) prefers the 32-bit version of dotnet.
To get the 64-bit version of dotnet, use: 
"D:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe" WEBJOBNAME.dll %*